# Bootrsap span and row doesn't work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to use bootsrap but it doesn't affect my layout. I want the layout to be like this (the colors and boxes helps to give you an idea of where on the screen the text should be):[image]

Instead it look like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/top.css">
<link
    href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light|Gloria+Hallelujah|Architects+Daughter'
    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>Top</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                Fluid 12
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        Fluid 6
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
                            <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span` and `row-fluid` are deprecated in bootstrap 3 onwards.

Just use `container-fluid` and keep a `row` div instead of `row-fluid` and use `col-xs` instead of `span` like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">....</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">....</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at the documentation here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

As mentioned below, the version has changed but for a layout that you are looking for I would use something like this (click full page when you run the snippet):

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
.col-md-6, .col-md-12, .col-md-3 {
    background-color:grey;
  margin:5px 0;
  border-radius:3px;
  }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      12
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      6

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      6
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      3
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      3
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are some very useful examples too!